# Reverse the position of form elements on a mouse click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am working on a hexadecimal to decimal color code converter. I wish to change the positions of the form elements on the click of a button.

i.e when i click hexa to deci button the form that takes hexadecimal code must appear on the left and when i deci to hexa button the form that takes decimal code must appear first.

[my work at codepen](http://codepen.io/RakshithNM/pen/pyjEOL)

**HTML CODE :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>my color converter</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>TOGGLE COLOR REPRESENTATION</h3>

        <div class="align text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default button1">HEXA TO DECI</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default button2">DECI TO HEXA</button>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 column1">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group colorcode1">
                        <label for="hex2decimal" class="class1"><p>COLOR IN DECIMAL CODE</p></label>
                    <input type="colorcode" class="form-control .class2" id="colorcode1" placeholder="decimal code">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group colorcode2">
                        <label for="hex2decimal" class="class3"><p>COLOR IN HEXADECIMAL CODE</p></label>
                        <input type="colorcode" class="form-control class4" id="colorcode2" placeholder="hex code">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="align text-center">
             <button class="btn btn-default button3">CONVERT</button>
             <button class="btn btn-default button4">REFRESH</button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS CODE :**

```
.form-group {
margin-top: 60px;
width:80%;
margin-left:8.33333333%;
text-align: center;
   } 

h3 {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:40px;
   }

.align {
    margin-top:40px;
   }
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button1").on('click',function(){
    var form1 = $('.colorcode1').detach();
       form1.appendTo('form');
                                   });
                             });
```

Note: I am learning Jquery and i have included the CDN.

Comment: It might be better, instead of trying to duplicate the form containing the answer, to just populate the answer in the opposite form field? The way Google Translate just shoves the translated answer in the opposite box.

Answer (score 1):

see working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/374t0kam/1/). your javascript will be as follows:
[codepan](http://codepen.io/dipalivasani/pen/JXbgVW)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button1").on('click', function() {
    var form1 = $('.colorcode1');
    var form2 = $('.colorcode2');
    jQuery(form1)
       .detach()
       .appendTo('#hax');
       jQuery(form2)
       .detach()
       .appendTo('#dec');
  });
  $(".button2").on('click', function() {
    var form1 = $('.colorcode1');
    var form2 = $('.colorcode2');
    jQuery(form1)
       .detach()
       .appendTo('#dec');
       jQuery(form2)
       .detach()
       .appendTo('#hax');
  });
});
```

HTML :

```
<h3>TOGGLE COLOR REPRESENTATION</h3>

<div class="align text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-default button1">HEXA TO DECI</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default button2">DECI TO HEXA</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 column1">
    <form id="dec">
      <div class="form-group colorcode1">
        <label for="hex2decimal" class="class1">
          <p>COLOR IN DECIMAL CODE</p>
        </label>
        <input type="colorcode" class="form-control .class2" id="colorcode1" placeholder="decimal code">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form id="hax">
      <div class="form-group colorcode2">
        <label for="hex2decimal" class="class3">
          <p>COLOR IN HEXADECIMAL CODE</p>
        </label>
        <input type="colorcode" class="form-control class4" id="colorcode2" placeholder="hex code">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="align text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-default button3">CONVERT</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default button4">REFRESH</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I am just learning jQuery, could you please tell why this is used? form1.appendTo('#');

Comment: @RakshithBellare : it was by mistake. I have removed and updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I added this to your style:

```
.column1 {
  float: right;
}
```

and then changed the js like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button1").on('click', function() {
    $('.colorcode1').parents('div:first').toggleClass('column1');
    $('.colorcode2').parents('div:first').toggleClass('column1');
  });
});
```

I would call the class something else than column1, though.